# Pandas Dataframe: change columns, index and plot

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, counter

[image: output]

Hi, I generated the table above using Counter from collections for counting the combinations of 3 variables from a dataframe: Jessica, Mike, and Dog. I got the combination and their counts.
Any help to make that table a bit more prettier? I would like to rename the index as grp1, grp2, etc and the column as well with something else than 0.
Also, what would be the best plot to use for plotting the different groups?
Thanks for your help!!

I used this command to produce the table here:
df= np.random.choice(["Mike", "Jessica", "Dog"], size=(20, 3))

Z= pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

import collections

from collections import Counter

LL= Z.apply (Counter, axis= "columns").value_counts()

H= pd.DataFrame(LL)

print(H)

Comment: This problem is probably best solved **before** this step, so you should provide a sample of your data that we can use to show you how to properly aggregate it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples gives examples of how to make sample data.

Comment: I used the following to generate the table above:
df= np.random.choice(["Mike", "Jessica", "Dog"], size=(20, 3))
Z= pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['a', 'b', 'c']) and then on a new line  import collections
from collections import Counter
LL= Z.apply (Counter, axis= "columns").value_counts()
H= pd.DataFrame(LL)
H

Comment: Please edit your question to include this code snippet. It's not portable in its current state.

Answer (score 0):

- quite an unusual technique....
- you can change the **dict** index to a multi-index
- then `plot()` as **barh** and labels make sense

```
df= np.random.choice(["Mike", "Jessica", "Dog"], size=(20, 3)) 
Z= pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['a', 'b', 'c']) 
import collections 
from collections import Counter 
LL= Z.apply (Counter, axis= "columns").value_counts() 
H= pd.DataFrame(LL) 
I = pd.Series(H.index).apply(pd.Series)
H = H.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(I.T.values, names=I.columns))
H.plot(kind="barh")
```

#### H after setting as multi-index

```
                  0
Mike Dog Jessica   
2.0  1.0 NaN      5
     NaN 1.0      4
NaN  1.0 2.0      3
1.0  NaN 2.0      3
     1.0 1.0      2
NaN  NaN 3.0      1
     2.0 1.0      1
3.0  NaN NaN      1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using counter, you can apply value_counts directly to each row:

```py
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Hard Coded For Reproducibility
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {0: 'Dog', 1: 'Jessica', 2: 'Mike',
                         3: 'Dog', 4: 'Dog', 5: 'Dog',
                         6: 'Jessica', 7: 'Jessica',
                         8: 'Dog', 9: 'Dog', 10: 'Jessica',
                         11: 'Mike', 12: 'Dog',
                         13: 'Jessica', 14: 'Mike',
                         15: 'Mike',
                         16: 'Mike', 17: 'Dog',
                         18: 'Jessica', 19: 'Mike'},
                   'b': {0: 'Mike', 1: 'Mike', 2: 'Jessica',
                         3: 'Jessica', 4: 'Dog', 5: 'Jessica',
                         6: 'Mike', 7: 'Dog', 8: 'Mike',
                         9: 'Dog', 10: 'Dog', 11: 'Dog',
                         12: 'Dog', 13: 'Jessica',
                         14: 'Jessica', 15: 'Dog',
                         16: 'Dog', 17: 'Dog', 18: 'Jessica', 19: 'Jessica'},
                   'c': {0: 'Mike', 1: 'Dog', 2: 'Jessica',
                         3: 'Dog', 4: 'Dog', 5: 'Dog', 6: 'Dog',
                         7: 'Jessica', 8: 'Mike', 9: 'Dog',
                         10: 'Dog', 11: 'Mike', 12: 'Jessica',
                         13: 'Jessica', 14: 'Jessica',
                         15: 'Jessica', 16: 'Jessica',
                         17: 'Dog', 18: 'Mike', 19: 'Dog'}})

# Apply value_counts across each row
df = df.apply(pd.value_counts, axis=1) \
    .fillna(0)

# Group By All Columns and
# Get Duplicate Count From Group Size
df = pd.DataFrame(df
                  .groupby(df.columns.values.tolist())
                  .size()
                  .sort_values())

# Plot
plt.figure()
df.plot(kind="barh")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

df after groupby, size, and sort:

```
                  0
Dog Jessica Mike   
0.0 3.0     0.0   1
1.0 2.0     0.0   1
0.0 2.0     1.0   3
1.0 0.0     2.0   3
3.0 0.0     0.0   3
2.0 1.0     0.0   4
1.0 1.0     1.0   5
```

Plt:

[image]